# web api dbcontext.add calls dispose() from AccountController class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an AccountController class that handles a POST request and creates an object of db repository class

```
        VoiceChatServiceRepository db = new VoiceChatServiceRepository();

        userDataModel.Avatar = DefaultLogo;
        userDataModel.Id = user.Id;
        userDataModel.FriendList = "";

        db.Add(userDataModel);
```

VoiceChatServiceRepository class contains:

```
    private VoiceChatServiceContext db = new VoiceChatServiceContext();

    public IEnumerable<UserDataModel> GetAll()
    {
        return db.UserDataModels;
    }

    public void Add(UserDataModel userDataModel)
    {
        db.UserDataModels.Add(userDataModel);   <-- Here is a problem
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My issue is that i cannot figure out why db.UserDataModels.Add(userDataModel) calls

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

from the AccountController class and i get an "Internal Server Error".

My config:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IVoiceChatServiceRepository, VoiceChatServiceRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

P.S. I follow this guideline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection to protect my code from DI

Call Stack: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiWvC.png)

Comment: `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` What class is that code in?

Comment: AccountController. I have no idea why VoiceChatServiceContext calls a method from this class just in next 'debug' step

Comment: @ElnurAlimirzayev quick correction.  You say you are "protecting your code from DI", I want you to understand that Dependency Injection is not a bad thing, you _want_ to have that in your applications.  It might be worthwhile to follow some tutorials/blog posts on Dependency Injection so that you might understand it better.

Comment: Can you remove all the code from controller method and just return empty result from there and check if Dispose methodd is still executing?

Comment: @ChatanRanpariya controller works correctly. I've found out that it happens when Dispose() called in my UnityResolver class, which supposed to resolve DIs. UnityResolver implemented like in a guide above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was in db connection string (unused "attached" *.mdf file).